# Convert UInt8 to character UTF8

Tags: swift

My code for converting UInt8 to character is:

```
for item in array {       
    print(Character(UnicodeScalar(item)))
}
```

the data in array is:

```
[10, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 105, 100, 14, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 76, 111, 110, 103, 1, 0, 0, 0, 97, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 1, 0, 0, 0, 98, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 1, 0, 0, 0, 99, 2, 0, 0, 0, 91, 66, 1, 0, 0, 0, 100, 2, 0, 0, 0, 91, 66, 1, 0, 0, 0, 102, 2, 0, 0, 0, 91, 66, 1, 0, 0, 0, 101, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 66, 111, 111, 108, 101, 97, 110, 9, 0, 0, 0, 116, 121, 112, 101, 95, 99, 111, 100, 101, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 8, 0, 0, 0, 103, 114, 111, 117, 112, 95, 105, 100, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 10, 0, 0, 0, 103, 114, 111, 117, 112, 95, 99, 111, 100, 101, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 180, 216, 174, 216, 167, 216, 181, 32, 216, 170, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 48, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 54, 49, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 180, 216, 174, 216, 167, 216, 181, 32, 216, 186, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 170, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 48, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 51, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 32, 216, 180, 216, 177, 217, 131, 216, 167, 216, 161, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 51, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 48, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 53, 57, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 54, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 216, 167, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 173, 216, 179, 216, 167, 216, 168, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 47, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 174, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 54, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 48, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 53, 56, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 216, 181, 217, 134, 216, 175, 217, 136, 217, 130, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 55, 54, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 48, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 116, 101, 115, 116, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 116, 101, 115, 116, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 50, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 179, 217, 134, 216, 167, 216, 175, 32, 217, 134, 216, 178, 216, 175, 32, 216, 181, 217, 134, 216, 175, 217, 136, 217, 130, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 56, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 216, 170, 217, 134, 216, 174, 217, 136, 216, 167, 217, 135, 32, 218, 175, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 217, 134, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 55, 51, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 56, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 216, 168, 216, 167, 217, 134, 217, 131, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 53, 52, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 179, 217, 134, 216, 167, 216, 175, 32, 216, 175, 216, 177, 32, 216, 172, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 134, 32, 217, 136, 216, 181, 217, 136, 217, 132, 32, 217, 134, 216, 178, 216, 175, 32, 216, 168, 216, 167, 217, 134, 217, 131, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 53, 53, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 48, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 180, 216, 174, 216, 167, 216, 181, 32, 216, 170, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 32, 40, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 41, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 53, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 180, 216, 174, 216, 167, 216, 181, 32, 216, 186, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 170, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 32, 40, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 41, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 54, 55, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 51, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 32, 216, 180, 216, 177, 217, 131, 216, 167, 216, 161, 32, 40, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 41, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 51, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 56, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 52, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 217, 133, 217, 136, 216, 172, 217, 136, 216, 175, 219, 140, 32, 217, 131, 216, 167, 217, 132, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 185, 217, 133, 217, 136, 217, 133, 219, 140, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 217, 133, 46, 32, 217, 131, 216, 167, 217, 132, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 185, 217, 133, 217, 136, 217, 133, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 52, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 56, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 217, 190, 217, 138, 216, 180, 226, 128, 140, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 174, 216, 170, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 52, 54, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 43, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 217, 129, 216, 167, 216, 177, 216, 180, 216, 167, 216, 170, 32, 217, 131, 216, 167, 217, 132, 216, 167, 32, 217, 136, 32, 216, 167, 216, 185, 216, 170, 216, 168, 216, 167, 216, 177, 216, 167, 216, 170, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 51, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 51, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 217, 131, 216, 167, 216, 177, 32, 216, 175, 216, 177, 32, 216, 172, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 134, 32, 217, 190, 216, 177, 217, 136, 218, 152, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 51, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 52, 50, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 52, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 52, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 216, 177, 217, 133, 216, 167, 217, 138, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 218, 175, 216, 176, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 32, 216, 175, 216, 177, 32, 216, 179, 216, 167, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 180, 216, 177, 217, 131, 216, 170, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 52, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 54, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 53, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 53, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 217, 136, 216, 175, 216, 167, 217, 138, 216, 185, 32, 217, 136, 32, 216, 179, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 53, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 48, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 54, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 54, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 79, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 216, 167, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 173, 216, 179, 216, 167, 216, 168, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 47, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 174, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 32, 40, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 41, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 54, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 55, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 56, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 216, 167, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 177, 216, 167, 216, 166, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 56, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 55, 50, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 56, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 217, 133, 217, 136, 216, 167, 217, 132, 32, 217, 136, 32, 217, 133, 216, 167, 216, 180, 217, 138, 217, 134, 226, 128, 140, 216, 162, 217, 132, 216, 167, 216, 170, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 52, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 57, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 177, 216, 167, 216, 166, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 175, 216, 177, 32, 216, 172, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 134, 32, 216, 170, 217, 131, 217, 133, 217, 138, 217, 132, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 48, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 217, 133, 216, 174, 216, 167, 216, 177, 216, 172, 32, 217, 130, 216, 168, 217, 132, 32, 216, 167, 216, 178, 32, 216, 168, 217, 135, 216, 177, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 216, 168, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 55, 48, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 216, 177, 217, 133, 216, 167, 217, 138, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 218, 175, 216, 176, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 168, 217, 132, 217, 134, 216, 175, 32, 217, 133, 216, 175, 216, 170, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 55, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 216, 179, 216, 167, 217, 138, 216, 177, 32, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 177, 216, 167, 216, 166, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 171, 216, 167, 216, 168, 216, 170, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 48, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 51, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 216, 173, 217, 130, 32, 216, 167, 217, 132, 216, 167, 217, 133, 216, 170, 217, 138, 216, 167, 216, 178, 217, 135, 216, 167, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 53, 55, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 52, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 216, 173, 217, 130, 32, 216, 179, 216, 177, 217, 130, 217, 129, 217, 132, 219, 140, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 51, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 52, 52, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 53, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 216, 167, 216, 179, 217, 134, 216, 167, 216, 175, 32, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 174, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 32, 216, 168, 216, 167, 217, 134, 217, 131, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 49, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 52, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 54, 53, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 54, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 217, 136, 216, 167, 217, 133, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 174, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 32, 217, 131, 217, 136, 216, 170, 216, 167, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 217, 133, 216, 175, 216, 170, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 52, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 52, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 55, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 66, 0, 0, 0, 216, 173, 216, 181, 217, 135, 32, 216, 172, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 32, 217, 136, 216, 167, 217, 133, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 217, 190, 216, 177, 216, 175, 216, 167, 216, 174, 216, 170, 217, 134, 219, 140, 32, 216, 168, 217, 132, 217, 134, 216, 175, 226, 128, 140, 217, 133, 216, 175, 216, 170, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 49, 51, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 52, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 55, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 51, 56, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 50, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 41, 0, 0, 0, 217, 190, 217, 138, 216, 180, 226, 128, 140, 216, 175, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 129, 216, 170, 32, 216, 167, 216, 178, 32, 217, 133, 216, 180, 216, 170, 216, 177, 217, 138, 216, 167, 217, 134, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 135, 226, 128, 140, 216, 180, 216, 175, 217, 135, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 216, 168, 217, 135, 46, 32, 217, 129, 46, 32, 216, 167, 217, 133, 217, 136, 216, 167, 217, 132, 32, 217, 136, 32, 217, 133, 216, 167, 216, 180, 217, 138, 217, 134, 226, 128, 140, 216, 162, 217, 132, 216, 167, 216, 170, 0, 6, 216, 168, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 216, 170, 217, 133, 216, 167, 217, 133, 226, 128, 140, 216, 180, 216, 175, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 219, 140, 32, 216, 179, 216, 177, 217, 133, 216, 167, 217, 138, 217, 135, 226, 128, 140, 218, 175, 216, 176, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 128, 140, 218, 175, 216, 176, 216, 167, 216, 177, 219, 140, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 168, 217, 132, 217, 134, 216,  135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 167, 217, 134, 216, 170, 216, 184, 216, 167, 217, 133, 219, 140, 0, 0, 216, 183, 216, 177, 217, 129, 32, 216, 173, 216, 179, 216, 167, 216, 168, 226, 128, 140, 217, 135, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 167, 217, 134, 216, 170, 216, 184, 216, 167, 217, 133, 219, 140, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 55, 50, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 48, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 57, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 54, 51, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 55, 53, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 48, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 59, 0, 0, 0, 216, 168, 216, 177, 218, 175, 216, 180, 216, 170, 32, 216, 167, 216, 178, 32, 217, 129, 216, 177, 217, 136, 216, 180, 32, 217, 133, 217, 136, 216, 172, 217, 136, 216, 175, 219, 140, 32, 217, 131, 216, 167, 217, 132, 216, 167, 219, 140, 32, 216, 185, 217, 133, 217, 136, 217, 133, 219, 140, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 216, 168, 46, 32, 217, 129, 46, 32, 217, 133, 46, 32, 217, 131, 216, 167, 217, 132, 216, 167, 219, 140, 1]
```

and result should be:
`1310 ریتجاfalse31010612320اشخ غ تریfalse3201013330جای`

but i get result like:
`1310 ÙÙÙfalse31010612320ÙÙÙÙÙfalse3201013330ÙÙÙ`

It works for English characters but for character in Persian language it is not working. Any body can help me?

Comment: What encoding are you using to fit a persian character into `UInt8`?

Comment: String.Encoding.utf8

Comment: What does `array` contain? Please show a concrete example.

Comment: [10, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 105, 100, 14, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 66, 111, 111, 108, 101, 97, 8, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 10, 0, 0, 0, 103, 114, 111, 117, 112, 95, 99, 111, 100, 101, 17, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 167, 216, 181, 32, 216, 170, 216]

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not to the comments. – What would be the expected result? There are a lot of zeros in that array, and it is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: How did you create the data? The initial bytes do not correspond to "1310..." in any sense. On the other hand the array contains strings like "java.lang.Integer", so it seems that you serialized an object in Java, but not to UTF-8.

Comment: Converting `1310 ریتجاfalse31010612320اشخ غ تریfalse3201013330جای` to byte array gave me `[49, 51, 49, 48, 32, 216, 177, 219, 140, 216, 170, 216, 172, 216, 167, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 51, 49, 48, 49, 48, 54, 49, 50, 51, 50, 48, 216, 167, 216, 180, 216, 174, 32, 216, 186, 32, 216, 170, 216, 177, 219, 140, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 51, 50, 48, 49, 48, 49, 51, 51, 51, 48, 216, 172, 216, 167, 219, 140]`. And this sequence is reverse-convertable. So you should check your `String->[UInt8]` conversion too.

Comment: > `but i get result like: 1310 ÙÙÙfalse31010612320ÙÙÙÙÙfalse3201013330ÙÙÙ`, How? As @MartinR said, and i personally checked your array using your conversion method will result in something like `idjava.lajava.lang.Booleaa.lang.Integer
group_codejava.lang.Integer71§Øµ ØªØ`

Comment: i said for example its result of middle of array

Comment: @behnam27, can you give array that actually represents your original string? Because there's no benefit of having data array that **cannot** be converted to your expected string. It just makes no sense giving example like this.

Comment: i have to remove some of array because of stackoverflow limitation on question length

Comment: Please tell us how you *created* the data, otherwise we can only guess about the problem.

Comment: It makes no sense to "just cast it to UTF-8 text" if the array does not contain valid UTF-8 data. It contains additional information as binary data, which might be offsets, tags, actual data, or whatever. Without knowing the data *format* this question cannot be answered reasonably.

Comment: @behnam27, we can't help you using **random** memory dump or something. Please edit your question and provide: a) original string, b) original string's byte array (instead of your random array), c) incorrect result of your `[UInt8] -> String` conversion.

Comment: The answer of @user2843 help me to correct my code. I should convert sequence of UInt8 to UTF8. Tnx for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're converting **each** byte separately to the string, while UTF-8 is multibyte encoding, only characters that could be represented are 0-127(`0x00`-`0x7f`) characters from old ASCII table (numbers, basic latin characters, etc.), other characters will be encoded using **2-4 bytes**.

So, `UInt8` sequence should be converted using code like this:

```
let data = Data(bytes: array)
let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: Also, your array from comment to the question is not valid utf8 byte sequence.